# Exclude MFA from Access Package Site

Tags: azure-active-directory, multi-factor-authentication

Is there a way to exclude an access package site from requiring MFA for external users?

Answer (score 1):

No we can't exclude a particular page from Conditional Access MFA.

Please raise user voice on this in [Azure feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) portal

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_0ujELj8i7auUA3b&Q_CHL=gl
>